# What is the best way to number form entries in Freeform?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I am trying to number Form submissions using an incrementing number that would display in Email Notifications.

[Increment Plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/increment) Field produces an incrementing number and would be ideal but it doesn't work because Freeform uses its own field type set.

What would be the best way to generate and associate a unique number per form entry that could then be displayed?

Comment: Just put {{ entry.id }} in the field's value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without creating a plugin, a "cheat" way would be to use the entry id of the submitted form - that would guarantee that you have a unique number and, assuming they are being saved to the same section, they would be in sequence.

Comment: Yes, they are indeed in sequence. What would be the best way to print the entry id in the subject field or in the template?